# How to synchronize Firestore rules and indexes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firebase project, which uses Firestore. I often manually modify security rules and indexes on the Firebase console, but I also have local copies on my dev machine (`firestore.rules` and `firestore.indexes.json`), which become out of sync when I do so.

Is there a way to automatically sync them? For example, if I create an index in the console, how do I then persist that index in my `firestore.indexes.json`?

So far I am manually applying those changes to local copies, but that is obviously an error prone process, and I'm trying to avoid accidentally overriding with out-of-date indexes or rules.

Comment: I don't know if the question is "opinion based" but it's a real problem and the answer and comments contain real, useful solutions. No need to open it again, but it should not have been closed.

Comment: agree ... this question is very relevant and well written. No reason to close it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is no automatic mechanism to handle conflicts between the Security rules declared in the Firebase console and the rules declared locally that get deployed when you deploy with the CLI.

**If your local project is set-up to deploy the Firestore security rules they will overwrite the rules in the console when you deploy with the CLI.** (See this documentation item: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy#edit_and_update_your_rules)

There are two possible approaches:

1. Set-up your local project to deploy the Firestore security rules through the CLI and **only modify the rules locally before deploying** (not super flexible)
2. Don't define the Security rules locally but only in the Firebase console. For that you should remove the `"rules": "firestore.rules"` line from the `firebase.json` file and remove the `firestore.rules` file from your project.

Note that "using the CLI allows you to keep your rules under version control with your application code".

---

**With indexes, things are a bit different**: if there are differences between the two versions (the local `firestore.indexes.json` file and the index in the console), you will get a warning in the terminal when deploying through the CLI:

```
i  firestore: there are some indexes defined in your project that are not present in your firestore indexes file. Run firebase firestore:indexes and save the result to correct the discrepancy.
i  firestore: there are some field overrides defined in your project that are not present in your firestore indexes file. Run firebase firestore:indexes and save the result to correct the discrepancy.
```

To update your local index JSON file, run `firebase firestore:indexes > firestore/firestore.indexes.json`.

Comment: Renaud where did you find this command? I cannot find it documented anywhere.

Comment: @phatmann it's part of the [firebase cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli). You can see the command usage help by running `firebase`

Comment: when the comment is better than the answer ^^

Comment: For some reason, my indexes.json file is just at root folder, not in the "firestore" folder. So if anyone is looking for the file, check there before creating a new one yourself.

Comment: @phatmann you should make your first comment an answer. helped me so much...